# UIView fixed frame

Tags: swift, uiview

I made a customView and I want the size of that view to be fixed.

 Like UISwitch in which you can't even change the height and width value. 
Or like UILabel. I want to add the view to storyboard without adding any height or width constraint with no missing constraint error. 
I already override intrinsicContentSize but I still get the missing constraint error. 
Is there any way to make height and width of a view constant that don't even get values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple solution

You can override the `intrinsicContentSize` variable and return the fixed size of your view.

So something like this should work in your custom view class:

```swift
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: <Your width>, height: <Your height>)
}
```

### More Advanced

Adding the `intrinsicContentSize` will work, but if a user adds a height constraint it can make the view confused or change the height of the view to match the constraint. If you **Know** the height of your custom view shouldn't change then you can manually change the height constraints from your view.

```swift
override func updateConstraints() {
    super.updateConstraints()
        
    if let constraint = self.constraints.first(where: { constraint in
        return constraint.isActive && constraint.firstAttribute == .height
    }) {
       constraint.constant = <Height of View>
    }
}
```

Ideally though, your best not adding this, but I'm just adding this here so it's an option if anyone needs it.